# will the space bar or return key add a special character to the argv charter pointer array?

Tags: objective-c, unix, terminal

Summary: 
I've been playing with unix terminal a bit lately and decided to to build a tiny Objective-C app in order to test how passing arguments to "main" will actually execute. I've build the app keeping std=c99 in mind.

The test: everything works fine if I hard code values to argv and argc hence: argv[0] and argv[1] from the first few lines in main.

The problem: If I comment argv[0] and argv[1] out and run my app from the unix terminal the app will never work and that is why I'm wondering if terminal will append any funny characters that I am not aware of --

Here's a snippet of the code: 
1. Note that Dictionary is just a struct
2. Thoughts?

```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //argv[0] = "prog";
    //argv[1] = "four";

    NSLog(@"request from: %s, entered string: %s, # of arguments: %i", argv[0], argv[1], argc);

    //argc = 2;
    if (argc >= 2)
    {
        if (translate(argv, argc));
        else
            NSLog(@"%s", "Unable to find request in dictionary");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"insufficient arguments");

    return 0;
}

    BOOL translate(char * search[], int size)
{
    const int buffer = 6;
    Dictionary dic[] =
    {{"one", "1"},
        {"two", "2"},
        {"three", "3"},
        {"four ", "4"},
        {"five", "5"},
        {"six", "6"}
    };

    char * temp = search[size - 1];
    NSLog(@"temp value: %s", temp);

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < buffer; ++i)
    {
        char * temp2 = dic[i].num;
        NSLog(@"steped into for loop - with currect struct value: %s", temp2);

        if (temp == temp2)
        {
            NSLog(@"steped into if stamtement");
            NSLog(@"%s", dic[i].translate);
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: `-std=C99`, really? Then why do you have Objective-C intermixed with your code?

Comment: 1. kept std=c99 in mind so that gcc doesn't complaint about the for loop in terimnal, I could have just add an extra line in gcc to skip the c99 error but I was lazy. 2. I have Objective-C code intermixed to debug and because I'm using the foundation framework to compile.

Comment: Fine. For the question: the shell separates the arguments by splitting the command line at spaces, not by reading your mind. So if you type `command -cmd John Brown` the argv will be `"command", "-cmd", "John", "Brown"`. You should quote the strings that contain spaces when entering the command line.

Comment: This is what I'm passing to terminal command line "./prog" "six" however it won't ever step into the if statement.

Comment: which one? There are plenty of them.

Comment: The if statement in the "translate" function.

Comment: I see... You can't compare strings like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ***one last time...***

You **cannot** compare strings using `==`, because C ain't JavaScript and `==` performs a numerical comparison on its operands. Instead of

```
if (temp == temp2)
```

you should write

```
if (strcmp(temp, temp2) == 0)
```

(and re-read a good C tutorial - in a decent one, "tricky" stuff like that is certainly included.)

Comment: Thanks! That is what I initially thought the problem was, however since I was originally testing and compiling from Xcode and because the compiler was producing the correct result it let me to believe there was a problem in how the character pointers were passed from command line.

Comment: Thanks so much! :) I was going a bit bananas given the many debug log attempts :P